# How to obtain, increment, and compare datetime in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I am developing a quiz site and there is  time for x min to answer the quiz. So when user clicks on start quiz link the starttime (current time at this instant) is recored in session. Also the endtime (start_time+ 30 min) is recorded in session and every time he submits a answer the current time is compared with the quiz end time. Only if the current time is less than end_time the answer should be accepted.

1. How can I get the currentdatetime?
2. How can I add x minutes to current this datetime?
3. How can I compare (<=) datetime ?

I think we should use date time. Is it right?

Answer (score 4):

PHP measures time as seconds since Unix epoch (1st January 1970). This makes it really easy to work with, since everything just a single number.

To get the current time, use: [`time()`](http://php.net/time)

For basic maths like adding 30 minutes, just convert your interval into seconds and add:

```
time() + 30 * 60  // (30 * 60 ==> 30 minutes)
```

And since they're just numbers, just do regular old integer comparison:

```
$oldTime = $_SESSION['startTime'];
$now = time();

if ($now < $oldTime + 30 * 60) {
    //expired
}
```

If you need to do more complicated things like finding the date of "next tuesday" or something, look at [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime), but you shouldn't need it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

use php builtin functions to get time:

```
 <?php
     $currentTimeStamp = time(); // number of seconds since 1970, returns Integer value
     $dateStringForASpecificSecond = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $currentTimeStamp);
 ?>
```

for your application that needs to compare those times, using the timestamp is more appropriate.

```
<?php
     $start = time();
     $end = $start + (30 * 60); // 30 minutes
     $_SESSION['end_time'] = $end;
?>
```

in the page where the quiz is submitted:

```
<?php
    $now = time();
    if ( $now <= $_SESSION['end_time'] ) {
         // ok!
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [time()](http://php.net/time) function to get a UNIX timestamp, which is really just a large integer.
2. The number returned by `time()` is the number of seconds since some date (like January 1, 1970), so to add `$x` minutes to it you do something like `(time() + ($x*60))`.
3. Since UNIX timestamps are just numbers, you can compare them with the usual comparison operators for numbers (`< <= > >= ==`)

Answer (score 0):

time() will give you the current time in seconds since 1/1/1970 (an integer), which looks like it should be good.

To add x minutes, you'd just need to add x*60 to that, and you can compare it like any other two integers.

Source: https://www.php.net/time

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I wanted to provide an answer based on the PHP 5.2 `DateTime` class which I feel is much easier to use and much more versatile than any previous functions.

### So how can i get the currentdatetime?

You can create a new DateTime object like this:

```
$currentTime = new DateTime();
```

But at this point, `$currentTime` is a datetime object and must be converted to a string in order to store it in a database or output it.

```
$currentTime = $currentTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $currentTime;
```

Outputs `2014-05-10 21:14:06`

### How can i add x minutes tocurrent this datetime?

You can add x minutes with the `modify` method:

```
$currentTime = new DateTime();
$addedMinutes = $currentTime->modify('+10 minutes');

echo $addedMinutes;
```

Outputs `2014-05-10 21:24:06`

### How can i comapare (<=) datetime ?

With the `DateTime` class, you can not only easily compare datetime objects, you can get the difference between them.

```
$currentTime = new DateTime('2014-05-10 21:14:06');
$addDays = $currentTime->modify('+10 days');
```

To compare

```
if ($currentTime >= $addDays) {
    //do something//
}

$diffTime = new DateTime('2014-05-10 21:14:06');
$diff = $addDays->diff($diffTime);
$diff = $diff->format('There are %d days difference.');

echo $diff;
```

Outputs `There are 10 days difference.`